# Quitar espacios al pegar en Excel desde DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, .net, excel, string

quiero pegar el contenido de un DataGridView en Excel. Sin embargo, el contenido de una columna, debido a que cada fila tiene blancos de sobra al final del string, hace que esta columna sea mucho más larga que el contenido.

Considerando que tengo este código para seleccionar lo que quiero pegar:

```
    dgv1.SelectAll()
    dgv1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(dgv1Operaciones.GetClipboardContent())
    Sheet.Range("A5").Select() 
    Sheet.Paste()
```

Cómo puedo aplicar Trim() en este caso, para que la columna afectada deje de alargarse más de lo debido? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: y no es mas facil limpiar los datos en la grilla? esto donde lo estas haciendo? desde vb o desde excel?

Comment: Desde VB traspaso los datos a un nuevo libro de Excel. Los datos están limpios pero al momento de pegar en el Excel, una de las columnas aparece con espacios al final

Comment: Que tal @KPavezC, puedes mostrar la cadena que te genera cuando haces la copia, para ver como poder eliminar los espacios.

Comment: @JulioMorenoDev , las cadenas que me pega en el Excel, tanto para los números como para los strings, las arroja así -> "algo________" , en donde los guiones bajos representan los blancos que no deberían estar y que quiero quitar.

Answer (score 1):

Tomando en cuenta tu código, esta sería una forma de hacerlo.

Al final, el replace lo que hace es reemplazarte los espacios por nada.

```
dgv1.SelectAll()
                dgv1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText.ToString().replace(" ", "");
                Clipboard.SetDataObject(dgv1Operaciones.GetClipboardContent())
                Sheet.Range("A5").Select() 
                Sheet.Paste()
```

Comment: Estimado, eso estaría sólo para el header, pero lo que necesito, es quitarle los blancos sobrantes al resto del contenido. Gracias de todas formas por su respuesta.

Comment: Aparte de eso, probé y extrañamente me aparecía un error de que no se puede convertir a Integer (muy raro)